# How to add 1 of 2 lists from a Class to another List?

Tags: c#, list

So I am working on my understandings of c# and I was trying to add a specific list into another list, but I am getting this error and don't know how to solve it.
I am trying to add a specific list of Pile (normalPile in my case) to the list of area.

**Container class:**

```
public enum KindOfContainer
{
    normal,
    cooled
}

public class Container
{

public int Weight { get; set; }

public  KindOfContainer kindOfContainer { get; }

public Container(KindOfContainer kindContainer, int Weight)
{
    this.kindOfContainer = kindContainer;
    this.Weight = Weight;
}
```

**Pile Class:**

```
public class Pile
{
    public List<Container> normalPile = new List<Container>();
    public List<Container> cooledPile = new List<Container>();

    public void AddContainer(Container container)
    {
        if(container.kindOfContainer == KindOfContainer.normal)
        {
            normalPile.Add(container);
        }

        else if (container.kindOfContainer == KindOfContainer.cooled)
        {
            cooledPile.Add(container);
        }
    }
}
```

**Area class:**

```
 public class Area
    {
        public List<Pile> area= new List<Pile>();

        public void VoegToe(Pile pile)
        {
            piles.AddRange(pile.normalPile);
        }
    }
```

So I am trying to add a list of containers (piles) to a list of Piles(area).
But when I do this I get the following error in my Area class:

Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<ListinListOefenen.Container> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ListinListOefenen.Pile>

I tried to do this:

```
public void VoegToe(Pile pile)
{
    area.AddRange((IEnumerable<Pile>)pile.normaPile);
}
```

But when I do my unit test I get the following error:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to convert an object of type System.Collections.Generic.List1 [ListinListOefenen.Container] to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1 [ListinListOefenen.Pile].

And I tried to do this:

```
  public void VoegToe(Pile pile)
    {
        area.Add((IEnumerable<Pile>)pile.normaPile);
    }
```

But here I get the following error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ListinListOefenen.Pile>' to 'ListinListOefenen.Pile'

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `normalPile` is `List<Container>` so it can not be added to `List<Pile>` and it can not be casted to `IEnumerable<Pile>`

Comment: I think you should do `piles.Add(pile)`